# How can i convert numeric value to datetime?

Tags: sql, datetime, numeric

i have a sql database

```
table name    :   TB_EVENT_LOG
columns name :   ndatetime,nuserid
```

column ndatetime has anumeric values like

> 1433923965,1433865660,1433841912,....

i want to convert all values in ndatetime column to date and time values

and preview that in datagridview

Comment: Why is ndatetime of numeric type when it seems it should be of date type? How do the numeric values relate to date+time?

Answer (score 0):

The example values you provided can be interpreted as seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the unix epoch). It depends on your programming environment how you would convert these values to presentable formats. Usually it involves the creation of Date(/Time) objects with the right constructor, or formatting with a right format string.

Comment: @MahmoudFathy, I made a similar [question and it has an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707629/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the numbers are total seconds since 1970-01-01. Check if the following SQL conversion is what you are looking for.

```
convert(datetime, dateadd(seconds, dateTimeInSeconds, '1970-01-01'))
```