# Convert integer value to DateTime in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table called "EventLog" which has the column called **nDateTime** of type `int`.

This is the table "EventLog" *with some values*:

```
-----------------
|   nDateTime   |
-----------------
|   978307200   |
-----------------
|   978307219   |
-----------------
|   978513562   |
-----------------
|   978516233   |
-----------------
|   978544196   |
-----------------
|   1450379547  |
-----------------
|   1472299563  |
-----------------
|   1472299581  |
-----------------
|   1472300635  |
-----------------
|   1472300644  |
-----------------
|   1472300673  |
-----------------
```

I need to get the DateTime value, and I tried the following statements, but I receive these errors:

**Test #1:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), nDateTime), 103) AS 'Formatted date'
FROM EventLog
```

The error says:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Test #2:** modified from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21874):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, nDateTime, 103) AS 'Formatted date'
FROM EventLog
```

And **Test #3** goes:

```
SELECT CAST(nDateTime AS datetime) AS 'Formatted date'
FROM EventLog
```

The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7830086/4092887) doesn't answer my question because (both, test #2 and test #3) generates this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

I admit that I never saw such value as a Date, and for that, I'm kind of confused in how to proceed.

My question is: How can get the valid DateTime value from the sample data?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830002/how-to-convert-int-to-date-in-sql-server-2008 Which states: "You can't convert an integer value straight to a date but you can first it to a datetime then to a date type "so... "`select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)`" other than version of SQL server 2008 vs 2012

Comment: @xQbert I already check that question, but the `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.` appears.  _sorry if I sound rude, my english isn't so good_

Comment: 1) "978307200" has 9 characters, not 8. 2) Can you give us any idea of where the number came from and what it represents, e.g. some number of milliseconds since some date?

Comment: @AndrewMorton 2) I honestly have no idea, unfortunately. I just receive a database and I'm check each table, no documentation or orientation received.

Comment: So you have no idea what date any of those numbers actually represent? So we have no way to verify the result?

Comment: @Jamiec, exactly, We (coworker and I) don't have more information.

Comment: So, you're not expecting much from an answer here I assume? Anyway, numbers like that usually represnt a number of X (seconds? Milliseconds? days!?!?) from a datum (usually 1 Jan 1970). If you have any *approximate* idea of when events were logged we may be able to guess

Comment: @Jamiec `you're not expecting much from an answer here I assume?` I don't understand. My coworker suggested that maybe? the date is represented in julian calendar, but we're not sure, we're checking the data in the database based on the names of the columns. That's all we know and we don't have more information.

Comment: Why would it be Julian calendar? Was your sofware written by the Romans in the 16th Century??

Comment: @Jamiec :D no idea, I told you :D, but seriously, I edited my question with more sample values. If this number? is not a date, what could be, or if you have faced similar situations, what you think about this value?

Comment: Yeah, you have something like Unix Time - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every time you see a date/time represented as an integer, that number represents the passage of time since a known epoch. This is the basis of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is, put simply, the number of seconds which have elapsed since `1st January 1970 00:00:00`

Using this, we can check with some values you have provided

```
declare @dt DATETIME = '1970-01-01' -- epoch start
print dateadd(second,978307200,@dt ) -- Jan  1 2001 12:00AM
print dateadd(second,1472300673,@dt )  -- Aug 27 2016 12:24PM
```

Seems possible, but who knows?!

You can check every date in your table simply using

```
declare @dt DATETIME = '1970-01-01' -- epoch start
SELECT
   nDateTime AS OriginalData,
   DATEADD(second, nDateTime,@dt) AS ActualDateTime
FROM EventLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for giggles, I took a stab at having the base date of 1970-01-01, but without KNOWING the base, it is just a guess

```
Declare @Log table (DateInt int)
Insert Into @Log values
(978307200),
(978307219),
(978513562),
(978516233),
(978544196),
(1450379547),
(1472299563),
(1472299581),
(1472300635),
(1472300644),
(1472300673)

Select DateInt,Converted= DateAdd(SECOND,DateInt,'1970-01-01') From @Log
```

Returns

```
DateInt     Converted
978307200   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
978307219   2001-01-01 00:00:19.000
978513562   2001-01-03 09:19:22.000
978516233   2001-01-03 10:03:53.000
978544196   2001-01-03 17:49:56.000
1450379547  2015-12-17 19:12:27.000
1472299563  2016-08-27 12:06:03.000
1472299581  2016-08-27 12:06:21.000
1472300635  2016-08-27 12:23:55.000
1472300644  2016-08-27 12:24:04.000
1472300673  2016-08-27 12:24:33.000
```

Answer (score 0):

**The "2038" Problem with Unix Timestamps**

There's a serious issue with writing code to convert UNIX Timestamps that are based on seconds... DATEADD can only handle INTs and that brings us to the "2038/Y2K38/Friday the 13th" problem (the day of the week when then "wraparound" to the most negative number an INT can have happens after the date below).

That means that the largest positive value it can handle is 2147483647.  If we use DATEADD to add that number of seconds to the UNIX Epoch of the first instant of the year 1970, we end up with a DATETIME that clearly explains what they mean by the "2038" issue.

```
 SELECT DATEADD(ss,2147483647,'1970');
```

[image: Largest Possible Date for UNIX Timestamp in Seconds]

**The Standard Fix for the "2038" Problem**

The standard way to get around that is to first store the UNIX Timestamp as a BIGINT and do two date adds... one for seconds and one for days.

There are 84600 seconds in a day. If we do Integer Division and ...

1. Use the Quotient to derive the number of days to add to
   '1970'...
2. And use the Remainder to derive the number of
   seconds to add to '1970'...

... we'll get the correct date not only for the MAX INT value...

```
DECLARE  @SomeUnixTS BIGINT = 2147483647
        ,@SecsPerDay BIGINT = 86400
;
 SELECT DATEADD(ss,@SomeUnixTS%@SecsPerDay,DATEADD(dd,@SomeUnixTS/@SecsPerDay,'1970'))
;
```

[image: Still the correct answer]

... but also for the last possible date in seconds for SQL Server. If we calculate the UNIX Timestamp (in seconds) for the last possible second that's available in SQL Server...

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(ss,'1970','9999-12-31 23:59:59');
```

[image: Last Possible Second in SQL Server]

... it still works with lots of room to spare and no "2038" problem.

```
DECLARE  @SomeUnixTS BIGINT = 253402300799
        ,@SecsPerDay BIGINT = 86400
;
 SELECT DATEADD(ss,@SomeUnixTS%@SecsPerDay,DATEADD(dd,@SomeUnixTS/@SecsPerDay,'1970'))
;
```

[image: Works 'til the End of SQL Server DateTime]

**UNIX Timestamps Based on Milliseconds**

Working with UNIX Timestamps that are based on Milliseconds are only slightly different but must be handled the same way...

```
DECLARE  @SomeUnixTS  BIGINT       = DATEDIFF_BIG(ms,'1970','9999-12-31 23:59:59.999')
        ,@msUnixEpoch DATETIME2(3) = '1970'
        ,@msPerDay    BIGINT       = 86400000
;
 SELECT  SomeUnixTS  = @SomeUnixTS
        ,msUnixEpoch = @msUnixEpoch
        ,Converted   = DATEADD(ms,@SomeUnixTS%@msPerDay,DATEADD(dd,@SomeUnixTS/@msPerDay,@msUnixEpoch))
;
```

[image]

As a bit of a sidebar, you have to wonder what Microsoft was or was not thinking when they created DATEDIFF_BIG() but didn't create a DATEADD_BIG().  Amazing even more is the they have SQL Server that will work in a UNIX environment and still no CONVERT(ts) functionality.

Here's whats new in 2022 in the area I'm talking about...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#language

And, last but not least, do not convert UNIX Timestamps that are based on milliseconds directly to DATETIME because the rounding in DATETIME can take you to the next day, week, month, and even year.  You must do a "units place" detection for "9" and "-1" and make the appropriate substitution of "7" and "-3" respectively.

Comment: p.s.  It magically works for Negative Timestamps, which are dates and times prior to the year 1970.

Answer (score -2):

Your input is > 8 digits hence it is throwing arithmentic overflow error.. If it is 8 digits you will get converted data:

For Example:

```
DECLARE @ndatetime int =  978307200 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @ndatetime, 112))
```

-- this throws arithmetic overflow error

```
DECLARE @ndatetime int =  97830720 -- with 8 digits only 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @ndatetime, 112))
```

This returns converted date

You can try try_convert which will return null if it is wrong date

```
DECLARE @ndatetime int =  978307200
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @ndatetime, 112))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the second sql statement in your question I get: `9783-07-20 00:00:00.000`. I'm wondering if those values are really datetime values...for example, if instead `97830720` you use `147402833`, the following error appears: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
`. I'll edit my question.

Comment: This answer just assumes those numbers represent a date - unless you're dealing with event logs from the year 9783, i find this very unlikely.

Comment: How you want to interpret the date 978307200 ? Any logic you have in mind?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I think thats the question!

Comment: This format 112 assumes that it is valid date for example 20160926 will be represented as date  '2016-09-26' ...